# Implement a back button in firefoxOS app

Tags: firefox-os

I have just started app development for the FirefoxOS. The simulator has just one 'Home' button, unlike that of android phones which have the 'Back' button also.

So, how do I implement a back button in my application? Because, if you just redirect the current page to the previous page, things like the form field values will be lost. Right?

Comment: are you using firefox building blocks for the ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
   <a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
   <h3>List of Notes</h3>
</div>
```

That `<a>` with the `data-rel="back"` does the trick!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From inside your app you can add your own back button/navigation UI and [manipulate the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to go back with `window.history.back();`

If your app was made for platforms that have a dedicated back button (like Android does) and you don't want to add you own  navigation in the app, you can also [add a browser toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Manifest#chrome) at the bottom of the app, by setting `"chrome": { "navigation": true }` at your manifest, but this will not provide the best user experience.